# Safari IOS, autoplay video when its visible on screen

Tags: javascript, html, ios, iphone

I am making a website with a similar scroll of (nearly) full screen videos to tiktok - however i am struggling to get ios safari to autoplay the videos as they appear on screen. I understand that ios cannot play unmuted videos without user interaction, but I am getting the first video to play via a button, so would expect the rest to work.

The sections in my code have some css that makes each section 1 full page and a css snap scroll makes 1 scroll go to the next page. Thats based on the code written here: https://codepen.io/team/css-tricks/pen/yLLqqgP

I have tried detecting and counting the amount of scrolls in JavaScript. If a user scrolls down once, then the second video plays, and if they scroll twice, the third video plays. However this is not working in IOS.

```
  <body>
    <section>
      <video id="myVideo1" height=400px controls loop playsinline>
        <source src="video1.mp4" type="video/mp4" autoplay>
      </video>
      <button id="playFirstVideo" onClick="document.getElementById('myVideo1').play();document.getElementById('myVideo1').muted=false">Play</button>
    </section>
    <section>
      <video id="myVideo2" height=400px controls loop playsinline muted>
        <source src="video2.mp4" type="video/mp4" autoplay>
      </video>
    </section>
    <section>
      <video id="myVideo3" height=400px controls loop playsinline>
        <source src="video3.mp4" type="video/mp4" autoplay>
      </video>
    </section>
    <script>
      var count = 0;
      window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
        var distanceY = window.pageYOffset
        if (distanceY > 0) {
          count++;
          if (count === 1) {
            document.getElementById("myVideo2").play();
            document.getElementById("myVideo2").muted = false;
           document.getElementById("myVideo1").pause();
          }
          if (count === 2) {
            document.getElementById("myVideo3").play();
            document.getElementById("myVideo3").muted = false;
            document.getElementById("myVideo2").pause();
          }
        }
      });
    </script>
```